# Passing a Variable from Python to YAML, in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: python, bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a variable value from a Python Script into a YAML file to run on an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline. Im using the following code, in my YAML file:

```
- bash: |
studentName=$(sed -i {/$deploymentResult.properties.outputs.studentName.Value/'a\}' "/CreateEnvironment.ps1")
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=studentName]studentName"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputstudentName;isoutput=true]studentName"
```

But when It gets to using the Variable studentName in the App Service Name I get an error from the pipepline that says: Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'studentName' details.

Does anyone know anything about AzureDevOps Pipelines and how to do this?

PLEASE dont just post Microsoft Links to Azure DevOps material ive literally been over all of it.

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this question? Please let me know whether my answer below can help you and feel free to comment~

Comment: Hi I didnt get it working this way in the end there was something not right with SED, so I piped the variable through PowerShell into a JSON file uploaded it into Azure Blob Storage then downloaded it into the YAML file and it worked getting the variable value.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is missing `$` when setting the value. The correct scripts are:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=studentName]$studentName"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputstudentName;isoutput=true]$studentName"
```